# -serial pty in qemu, how to open?

Tags: serial-port, qemu, xterm, pty, pts

I am running qemu with

> -serial pty

option, and qemu gave this message

> char device redirected to /dev/pts/1

however, it doesn't generate new window, I can do `cat` on pts1 from different window,
but then I can't input any character to it.

Is there anyway you can start a new xterm with specific pts number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation is using screen. Supposing you get assigned /dev/pts/1, you should call, on another terminal, the following command:

```
# screen /dev/pts/1
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this, it seems that I can connect to the randomly-assigned pts with minicom.

Comment: Can you accept this answer so the question doesn't show up as unanswered?  Thanks!